# MS Outlook Rule that deletes emails with a specific size of attachment

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Very often I receive emails with MS Excel files that are empty. Knowing the exact size of such an empty file, I would like to force Outlook to move all those emails to trash. However, the available rules count the size of the entire message.

I do not want Outlook to count the size of an entire email. I want to apply my rule **only to the size of an attachment.**

For example:

```
If I receive an email from: xxx
with an attachment that is smaller that 60kb
move this email to trash
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm afraid there is not a build-in rule for this. You may go to outlook for developers forum for some code help.